# How do l solve issues on "Download Boot Loader 0%" on SP Flash Tool?

Tags: rom-flashing, sp-flash-tool

I bought a UMIDIGI A3 running Android 8.1. The phone got bricked after an upgrade was done via OTA.

I tried to restore the phone through the use of the SP Flash Tool. My problem is each time the process began, it got terminated on “Download Boot Loader 0 %”. Although this is weird because I haven’t had such experience with SP Flash Tool before.

[image]

How do I solve this issue and get back my phone?

Answer (score -1):

Uncheck *preloader* entry in that screen you shared in the screenshot and then click the Download process. I tested this and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).